# Determininig Association Rules with a given item set

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, data-mining, arules

Im trying to learn how to generate associate rules. If I say for example i have an item set  (a1=yes,b2=yellow, x3=round)? what kind of rules would be generated.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what is how frequent.